# Process maker 4 Installation Error window

Tags: processmaker

When I used **https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker** this link for package set up for window with laravel (PHP), but when  I run npm install ,**then The syntax of the command is incorrect.** and when run npm run dev commad , then **SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.**

What is the solution of this ?

I tried diiferent solutions, but not solved this issue.